# Using bold type for installed font in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, fonts

I'm using a palatino font in a matplotlib figure. Because the system is running Ubuntu 18.04, I created the subdirectory **/home/ubuntu/PalatinoF** where I put the **Palatino.tff** file. From some other threads, the font is loaded with:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager font_dirs =
['/home/ubuntu/PalatinoF', ] font_files =
font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=font_dirs) font_list =
font_manager.createFontList(font_files)
font_manager.fontManager.ttflist.extend(font_list)
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Palatino'
```

This has worked well except that it completely ignores the label `weight='bold'` or `fontweight='bold'` whenever used. To fix it, I uploaded the **Palatino_bold.tff** file in the subdirectory but the solution is even worse as it plots squares rather than the text. I also tried `plt.rcParams['font.bold'] = 'Palatino_bold'` but this is not an actual option. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `matplotlib.rc` which can control most of the font within the resulting plots.

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font', weight='bold')
```